# Conditional show button based on having a post

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

I have a Wordpress membership site (custom, no plugin) where users create a profile(page). In the navbar I want to display a link to that page, but only if the user has created a profilepage (which is a custom post type). How do I do that?
Something like:

**If user has post in postype > display button. 

Else display nothing.**

Answer (score 1):

Try like following

```
function chelsea_user_has_posts($user_id) {
  $result = new WP_Query(array(
    'author'=>$user_id,
    'post_type'=>'custiom_type',  //enter post type slug here
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'posts_per_page'=>1,
  ));
  return (count($result->posts)!=0);
}

function cross_check_user_items() {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if (chelsea_user_has_posts($user->ID)) {
      echo '<button></button>';
  } else {
    //show them the goods
  }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'cross_check_user_items');
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. And where do I add this? Can I put this in the Navbar?

Comment: Add in your theme functions.php and change post type slug with your custom post type slug

Comment: I did, but I don't want it to show in the admin area, but on the frontend. I build the site with Oxygen builder, so is there a way to make this a shortcode, which I can put anywhere I want? Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: change the hook from admin_head to your desired area for frontend. and yes. you can change it and make it one function and create shortcode to use anywhere